# Yii2 помогите разобраться с событиями

Tags: yii2, события, observer

Есть контроллер Item, actionCreate и в нем обработчик

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $item = new Item();

    $file = new File();

    $file->trigger(File::FILE_UPLOADS);

    if ( Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $item->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) )
    {
        $item->attributes = Yii::$app->request->post('Item');

        $errors = ActiveForm::validate( $item );
    }

    if( $errors )
    {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return $errors; 
    }
}
```

И модель File

```
class File extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    const FILE_UPLOADS = 'file-uploads';

    public function init()
    {
        $this->on(self::FILE_UPLOADS, [$this, 'uploads']);
    }

    public function uploads( $event )
    {
        $file = new File();

        if ( Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $file->load( Yii::$app->request->post() ) )
        {
                $file->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($file, "image");
        }

        $errors = ActiveForm::validate( $file );

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Файл передается на валидацию, вроде все ок, но не пойму как мне вернуть результат обратно в контроллер Item, т.е. вот эту часть ?

```
$errors = ActiveForm::validate( $file );
```

В идеале хочу польностью разделить Item и File, но пока что не понимаю как, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вашу проблему надо решить так:

```
сlass ItemController extends yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $item = new Item();
        $file = new File();

        $file->trigger(File::FILE_UPLOADS);

        Yii::$app->getResponse()->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($item->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $file->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post())) {
            if (!$item->validate()) {
                return \yii\helpers\Html::errorSummary($item);
            }

            if (!$file->validate()) {
                return \yii\helpers\Html::errorSummary($file);
            }

            //Ваш код...
        }
    }
}
```

То есть вынести валидацию из модели. Также почему вы наследуете модель *File* от \yii\db\ActiveRecord, а не от yii\base\Model ?